# Typical crankcase pressure range for a 2.0T gasoline engine

Tags: hyundai, pcv-valve

I'm putting together a oil "catch can" system for my Hyundai 2.0T (Theta II) engine. Instead of using a catch can, I plan to use a pneumatic coalescing filter, like a Parker-Watts F501/F507 type.

The collection bowl is relatively small, only about 1.5oz. I am not sure what the service interval will be yet; I am not sure how much oil blow-by there really is.

Given the small bowl, I wanted to add a pressure blow-off/bleed valve inline with the PCV tube, just incase the bowl fills up, and/or the filter element gets clogged up. Theoretically, it adds another level of safety to avoid high crankcase pressure.

However, I'm not sure what a typical range of crankcase pressure is from idle to full load. Google indicates between 2-6psi, but other users report <1psi. It of course varies by engine type. I want to size the relief valve in a reasonable way. 3psi rating? 6psi? Obviously the best way is to just measure it, but just trying to get a feel.

Thanks.

Comment: Fit a gauge and measure it.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. Obviously best way. I need to get a pressure gauge with full scale deflection range to match what I'm trying to measure. I can get 0-5PSI, 0-10PSI, 0-15PSI, etc. I don't want to get a 0-15PSI gauge if I'm measuring 0.5PSI.

Comment: I used to have several gauges so I did not face that problem. But having a range is always a good idea.